# How to detect the execution time of StopWatch guava?

Tags: java, guava

I’ve been working with guava recently, faced with such a question I want to measure the total time execution of the put (str) method, which puts the string in map . I try to do this with StopWatch and calculate the average time for the method to execute, but at the moment I am constantly returning 0

```
private int putCounter = 0;
    private Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    private CustomCache mapBasedCache = new MapBasedCache();

    @Override
    public void getEvictions(String str) {
        stopWatch.start();
        mapBasedCache.put(str);
        putCounter++;
        stopWatch.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public long getAveragePutTime() {
        return stopWatch.elapsedTime(TimeUnit.SECONDS) / putCounter;
    }
```

My test method:

```
public void getAveragePutTime() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10_000_000; i++){
            gg.getEvictions("ab" + i);
        }


        long time = gg.getAveragePutTime();
        System.out.println(time);
    }
```

Comment: Maybe it really is 0 seconds. One thing you could try to verify the `Stopwatch` is working correctly is by adding a `sleep` and see if you get something other than 0.

Comment: But if I doing somthing like this. I have 7 sec
stopwatch.start();
for (int i = 0; i < 10_000_000; i++){
                gg.getEvictions("ab" + i);
            }
stopwatch.stop();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it by casting to a `double`:

```
@Override
public double getAveragePutTime() {
    return (double)(stopWatch.elapsedTime(TimeUnit.SECONDS)) / putCounter;
}
```

Why?

Because you're dividing something like 10 seconds in the worst case by 10 millions. With longs and integers!!

In java, `(long)10 / (int)10_000_000` will give nothing else than `0`. So just cast a double somewhere.

Or better yet, use a more precise time unit:

```
@Override
public double getAveragePutTime() {
    return (double)(stopWatch.elapsedTime(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)) / putCounter
}
```